# Proper Use of COUNT to count number of rows returned in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, sql, count

```
SELECT FirstName,
       MiddleName,
       LastName,
       COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM Person.Person TABLESAMPLE(10 PERCENT)
```

Gives me the error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'Person.Person.FirstName'
>   is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: 2012: I'm trying to just list the number of rows returned in the query, I think maybe it would be better do just write a second select separate from this to return one row.

Comment: Why are you using `TABLESAMPLE` at all? Have you noticed that it doesn't consistently return the same number of rows (and that number may be significantly higher or significantly lower than 10 percent of the table)? And do you want the number of rows in the table, or the unpredictable and dynamic number of rows that are actually returned using `TABLESAMPLE`?

Comment: Because i'm going through a T_SQL tutorial that is attempting to teach me the use of TABLESAMPLE and I was wondering why it returned a different number of rows. I have in fact just posted that question.  I was trying to count the number of rows because I didn't realise the IDE told me this in the bottom right corner of the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, 
  [count] = COUNT(*) OVER()
 FROM Person.Person 
 TABLESAMPLE (10 PERCENT);
```

Though you may prefer the following, since `TABLESAMPLE` has some issues IIRC (for me, `TABLESAMPLE` returns an unpredictable number of rows every time, and it also prevents you from counting rows from the entire table):

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName,
  [count] = COUNT(*) OVER()
 FROM Person.Person 
 ORDER BY [something];
```

If you really want a random set of rows, you can use `ORDER BY NEWID();`. And if you want the actual count returned by the query, not the count of rows in the actual table, just follow your query (without the `COUNT` aggregate) with:

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Also please don't use `'single quotes'` for column aliases - this syntax is deprecated in some cases and also makes aliases look like string literals. When you need to escape aliases because they are keywords or contain spaces or otherwise violate identifier rules, use `[square brackets]`.

Comment: That's interesting, I'm doing a tutorial at trainsignal (from a Microsoft MVP) and he's telling me to use single quotes because it stands out more.

Comment: `[count] = COUNT(*) OVER()` << I don't understand this line could you elaborate for me?

Comment: Well it's subjective but I don't think entities should look like string literals.

Comment: @DavidFolksman: that's the Microsoft way of writing a column alias. In standard SQL that would be `count(*) over () as "count"`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think he was asking what the `COUNT(*) OVER()` bit meant, not the `=` vs. `AS` bit. And here is [why I buck the standard on this one](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases.aspx).

Comment: Interesting read, bookmarked to go over it in detail.  But, since i'm looking to pass a standardised exam, I'd like to learn the standard way of doing things before I change over.

Comment: yes I was asking what the `COUNT(*) OVER()` line meant sorry if I didnt clarify that properly.

Comment: Having read your blog, I still don't understand what `OVER()` is doing, sorry, newbie and all that.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: for someone *not* using Microsoft products on a daily basis that syntax looks *extremely* weird whereas window functions are so ubiquitous nowadays that I assumed it's the strange syntax that raised the question. I do disagree with that blog post - even though I do like most of the other "bad habits to kick posts because they promote using standard SQL where possible. It might be something "natural" for a Microsoft only person, but for others it's really strange (as are the weird `[..]` "quotes"). I usually need a second to realize that it's not an assignment but an alias.

Comment: In addition, should I be posting T-SQL questions in Stack Overflow and Not the Database site?  I just noticed I've been migrated.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's exactly why I said "it's subjective" above.

Comment: @David a lot of folks on the database site tend to think that simpler SQL-related programming questions belong over here. I don't feel that strongly either way.

Answer (score 2):

Everytime you are going to use any aggregate function (sum, count, avg, etc), you must identify your GROUP clause;

In your query, you are identifying how many rows you have for each Firstname, Middlename, and lastname:

```
    SELECT FirstName,
    MiddleName,
    LastName,
    COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
    FROM Person.Person TABLESAMPLE(10 PERCENT)
    GROUP BY FirstName, MiddleName,LastName;
```

If you want to know how many person you have:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
   FROM Person.Person TABLESAMPLE(10 PERCENT);
```

Comment: Your query for `how many person you have` actually returns the number of rows that happen to be produced by `TABLESAMPLE` - go ahead and run it, and run it again, the number is going to change, and does not reflect the total number of rows in the table.